# Nginx and try_flies not working properly

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, multiviews

I'm trying to simulate Multiviews, but i have a problem with try_files. All is ok, but i want to rewrite all urls not managed to /index.php (but no with 404):

```
location ~ ^(/.+)/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ $1.php?$args @extensionless-php /index.php;
}
location @extensionless-php {
   rewrite ^(.*)/ $1.php;
}
```

ALL urls are rewrited to /index.php. If i remove /index.php at the end of first location, everything is ok except the not managed url's (that i want to be rewrited to index). Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to remove `/index.php` from first location, as you said. Then, to make it redirect to `/index.php` when no php file found, you may add a few lines into the `location` which handles `.php` requests:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite    .*    /index.php;
    }
    # your other directives such as fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; etc.
}
```